# Is there any cooldown time between contracts?

Tags: contracts, spain

I am currently working on a Spanish company, I been hired to substitute a person, that person comes back to work in 4 days, according to law I can’t be working with the person I’m substituting, so, they will fire me in 3 days, and want to hire me again to substitute another person so I can come work the same day the substituted person comes back.

Note: Personally I wouldn’t mind If I had some days between contract and already told them but they insist on doing it this way.

Is this a legal thing? I assume it is but it sounds as a fudge to me.

Edit (to answer the question in comments) :

It's a "until the person comes back" substituting contract, im pretty new to working experiences but I assume with this type of contracts whenever the person your are substituting comes back you have to leave.

I also woudn't mind to know if I will get any extra paid for getting fired before the duration of contract but thats another question.

Note: I been working about 1 month. (Contract says 3 first months are trial period)

Update: In the end everything has gone well, they have already made me the new contract and it is the same as the previous one but replacing another person.

Comment: Fire you with no notice? Whats in your contract?

Comment: @Kilisi edited to answer

Comment: I also would note that they are super nice, and I dont expect any weird thing happening.

Comment: Weird is having a firing on your permanent work history, good luck explaining that it was just a formality to interviewers.

Comment: This feels like a really weird law... it completely blocks both "learning what you'll be doing from the person you're replacing" and "updating the person you've replaced on what you've been doing in their absence". I'm not familiar with Spanish law but it feels off to me.

Comment: Maybe I didnt explain myself, they will end this contract and start a new one, the job I will be doing before and after is the same. @Kilisi

Comment: Now I am more worried about the fire on my work history than about the legality of Fire to Hire :(

Comment: Why do they have you on a 6-month contract when the other person comes back after a month? Will your new contract have another 3-month trial period? Why can't they keep on your existing contract but simply change who you are substituting for, especially if the actual job is not changing?

Comment: I have to agree with you there @AndrewLeach I dont know why is it done this way.

Comment: Anyways on my CV I will ommit this gap between contracts and just place the total time worked.

Comment: It is legal, has been reformed recently, used to be called "contrato de interinidad". There is no notice period. Either way, I think this is not on-topic for Workplace as it is a jurisdiction specific legal question...

Comment: _"according to law I can’t be working with the person I’m substituting"_ this sounds made up. Please provide a reference for that law. This sounds more like a workaround/legal loophole to avoid having to give you a contract extension or a permanent contract. It sounds pretty shady, and I would expect this to be borderline illegal.

Comment: @Kilisi It is not "being fired." The contract did just end. It is as if the OP was contrated for 3 months, and the 3 months had passed. In this case, the time limit is set by the absence of the original employee, which is most often that not very difficult to predict exactly in advance.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Completely legal, the idea is to avoid business to use short term contracts when they should be using long term contracts that give more protections to workers. Check my answer.

Comment: @SJuan76 the question has changed, it said 'fired' originally

Comment: Kilisi: Firing and rehiring is usually done to prevent the person from gaining any rights that permanent employees would gain. @MarkRotteveel: In Germany they have a legal principle that reality beats contracts. If I would gain rights after twelve months, and you fire me after 11 months and rehire me immediately for another 11 months, a court would say that the reality is that I was hired for 22 months, and what the contract says doesn't matter.

Comment: @gnasher729 The same principle exists in the Netherlands (AFAIK), which is why some companies use a legal loophole where they will not extend your contract, and "allow" you to reapply after a number of weeks (though I guess that practice is uncommon with the current worker shortage).

Comment: The thing I would change is the trial period, for each new contract I have a new trial period time, is like I wont ever be non-trial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no cooldown.

There may be issues with chaining contracts, but it depends on how it is done. But if done wrong, the trouble is for the company, not for you.

Typically in Spain the longer your contract, the harder is for your employer to fire you. The employer cannot try to work around this by chaining short term contracts, so short terms contracts either must have a very well defined reason or have some reasonable cooldown to show that they are not a chained long term contract.

For example, you may be hired "por obra y servicio" to help building a house. Then the house is built, your contract ends, and you may be hired again "por obra y servicio" immediately to build another new house. But if you are hired "por obra y servicio" for building a house and the company uses you for other tasks (during or after that house is built), then you may become a de facto "regular employee". Then, if the company tries to fire you, it no longer can just end your contract, it is firing you and you can demand the same compensation that a regular employee would receive when being fired.

Replacement contracts work all the same. If it is a legitimate contract will be defined by the task you realize. If when replacing A you do A's job, and then when replacing B you do B's job, it is as it should be and the company is safe. But if, when you replace A, you do other tasks (let's say the company says that, since you have experience with A's tasks, you will continue doing those while replacing B), then it could be construed that it is not actually a replacement contract and the company is exposing itself.

But you are not doing anything wrong, these rules exists only to prevent the company from giving you less rights with the excuse of a replacement (that is the reason why you cannot work at the same time that the replaced worker, even if some times some overlap could be understandable).

Even if the company abuses the system, the rule of thumb I was given was to never protest as long as contracts keep coming, and to document everything (contracts, tasks...). Since the company can almost always fire you (the only difference is how much you get), you stay as long as you can, and when they no longer hire you, then you demand your compensation for being fired(*).

(*)Of course, it would be necessary for a lawyer to review the situation, and if it comes to a lawsuit, the results are often unpredictable. This is just a very basic explanation of how the system works.

Comment: Thanks for the info! @SJuan76, great answer!

Answer (score 0):

If both parties agree to end the contract and waive any conditions then there isn't a problem. And you're free to recontract or contract elsewhere.

If they intend to fire you, then that is a different matter because it will be a termination on your work history which never looks good.

I suggest you get that clarified as soon as you can.

Comment: It is a "both parties agree to end", maybe I shoudnt have used the word fired, as I dont think it even fits in this type of contract, it's just the way they work in Spain, when the person comes back you leave, no firing involved.

Comment: @Erik not if the contract says different. The contract is the legal agreement. What works best for the company isn't.

Comment: In Spain substitution contract usually have the lenght until the person comes back, maybe I mixed the maximum duration with the lenght.

Comment: Best to check and edit your question into something that reflects reality.

Answer (score 0):

It could be legal reasons and at the same time it could be that there is no law requiring that. Let me explain.

My personal guess: Hiring people as substitutes with a limited contract may have lower hurdles in your company structure (e.g. formal selection, review by boards, acceptance of labor council) than hiring a fixed new employee. Having contracts magically spill from temp being switched to fixed without a period may undermine these formalities, which is why it may be formally needed to "reapply". As to why there need to be a few days in between, i don't know and have no idea (I am not a lawyer), but it may be that all kind of funny questions arise around such a switch, which may be specific to you professional, company, insurance, regional and potentially communal regulations - for this ask a lawyer.